# Can't Interact With Controls In Table View Header

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchbar, uisegmentedcontrol

I've decided to use a table header view in my app to hold a search bar and a UISegmentedControl. Here is the `viewDidLoad` of the view controller:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 65, 320, 44)];
    [self.searchBar sizeToFit];
    [self.searchBar setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [self setSearchController:[[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:self.searchBar contentsController:self]];

    self.mainSegment = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:@[@"YouTube", @"iTunes"]];
    [self.mainSegment setFrame:CGRectMake(8, 109, 305, 29)];
    [self.mainSegment setSelectedIndex:0];
    [self.mainSegment addTarget:self action:@selector(searchTypeChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [self.mainSegment setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

    UIView* headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 65)];
    [headerView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [headerView addSubview:self.searchBar];
    [headerView addSubview:self.mainSegment];
    [headerView bringSubviewToFront:self.searchBar];
    [headerView bringSubviewToFront:self.mainSegment];
    [headerView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView;
    self.tableView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
}
```

This produces a good result:

[image]

However, I can't interact with the search bar or the segmented control. I tried setting userInteractionEnabled to YES as shown above, but the problem still remains. Any ideas?

Comment: Unresponsive controls are often the result of them being outside the bounds of their superview. Give your header view a different background color to see if they are within the bounds or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The height of your header view is 65 points. You're inserting your searchbar at Y=65 so it's beyond the bounds of the header rect. Move your searchbar to Y=0 and your segmented control below it, and it's going to work just fine.

Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0):

USe delegate methods to set up the headerview.Create and return your headerview in this method.

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

Dont forget to set up the table header height.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

and the `<UITableviewDatasource>` in header file to indicate the class is actually having your datasource methods to that table

[A must read doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html)

Comment: The OP is making a table header view, not a section header, so this is not the way to go.